# Cpanel account remote backup with remote ftp destination

Tags: php, backup, cpanel, whm

In older whm version (<64) i was able to call the full account backup function with curl, like this:

```
fputs($socket, "POST /frontend/" . $theme . "/backup/dofullbackup.html?" . $params . " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
```

But now it doesn't work anymore.

Can anybody suggest some script to make it work.
I have a lot of accounts and i made a php code that was creating backups and saving on ftp servers... Now it's not working.

Comment: Did you try reading the cPanel/WHM documentation related to that? https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Backup+Configuration#4c08fd1e49bc4a36bb31caf463fe72d0

Comment: Of course i did. I don't want to use the interface whm gives. I want my own php code to make a backup and transfer remotely logging in, without the need to put my script on the server i want to backup